# ASSERTION FAILED robot_localization error

Tags: navigation, ekf, ros-kinetic, xmlrpc, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. I am trying to run the package *robot_localization* however when I use my launch file it gives me this error;

```
[FATAL] [1542859479.759800234]: ASSERTION FAILED
file = /home/pg/ugv01_ws/src/maps_nav/robot_localization/src/ros_filter.cpp
line = 2313
cond = topicConfig.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeArray

[FATAL] [1542859479.769316425]: ASSERTION FAILED
file = /home/pg/ugv01_ws/src/maps_nav/robot_localization/src/ros_filter.cpp
line = 2313
cond = topicConfig.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeArray

[localisation/ekf_cont-2] process has died [pid 12445, exit code -5, cmd /home/pg/ugv01_ws/devel/lib/robot_localization/ekf_localization_node __name:=ekf_cont __log:=/home/pg/.ros/log/e35b3192-ee06-11e8-8312-78d00423a161/localisation-ekf_cont-2.log].
log file: /home/pg/.ros/log/e35b3192-ee06-11e8-8312-78d00423a161/localisation-ekf_cont-2*.log
 [localisation/ekf_disc-3] process has died [pid 12447, exit code -5, cmd /home/pg/ugv01_ws/devel/lib/robot_localization/ekf_localization_node odometry/filtered:=odometry/filtered_disc __name:=ekf_disc __log:=/home/pg/.ros/log/e35b3192-ee06-11e8-8312-78d00423a161/localisation-ekf_disc-3.log].
log file: /home/pg/.ros/log/e35b3192-ee06-11e8-8312-78d00423a161/localisation-ekf_disc-3*.log
```

Please help me to understand why this error is occurring and what steps I can take to resolve the issue?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309086/assertion-failed-robot_localization-error/) by [PG_GrantDare](https://answers.ros.org/users/38516/pg_grantdare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2018-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PG_GrantDare](https://answers.ros.org/users/38516/pg_grantdare/) on 2018-11-22**:
For anyone stumbling along this, I have NO IDEA what I did to fix it. I restarted and ran catkin_make a few more times and it worked? If anyone does have an answer I would love that incase it happens again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This usually indicates that your sensor configuration (the boolean array) was not formatted properly.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PG_GrantDare](https://answers.ros.org/users/38516/pg_grantdare/) on 2018-12-03**:
Thanks Tom, I did check over my config again and it worked.